# Wordpress wp_set_object_terms does not assign product to custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have create a custom taxonomy called `regions` with acf. and have create also a select option on dokan multivendor dashboard where they can create new product

```
<?php
$regions = get_terms([
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'show_option_none' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'taxonomy' => 'region'
]);
?>
    <label for="regions"><?php esc_html_e('Region', 'your-text-domain'); ?></label><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="region_id" id="region_id" value="">
    <select name="regions" class="dokan-form-control">
        <option value=""><?php esc_html_e('Select Region', 'your-text-domain'); ?></option>
        <?php foreach ($regions as $region) {
        $parent_categories = get_terms([
            'taxonomy' => 'region',
            'hide_empty' => false,
            'parent' => $region->term_id
        ]);
        if (!empty($parent_categories)) { // check if there are any child categories
            ?>
            <?php foreach ($parent_categories as $parent_category) {
                $child_categories = get_terms([
                'taxonomy' => 'region',
                'hide_empty' => false,
                'parent' => $parent_category->term_id
                ]);
                if (!empty($child_categories)) { // check if there are any child categories
                ?>
                <optgroup label="<?php echo $parent_category->name; ?>">
                    <?php foreach ($child_categories as $child_category) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $child_category->term_taxonomy_id; ?>" id="in-region-<?php echo $child_category->term_taxonomy_id; ?>"> <?php echo $child_category->name; ?> </option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </optgroup>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
```

and now i try to assign this post id when its created to regions like this

```
//path: dokan-lit/includes/Dashboard/Templates/Products.php

public function handle_product_add() {
    if ( isset( $postdata['add_product'] ) ) {
            $post_title     = sanitize_text_field( $postdata['post_title'] );
            $post_content   = wp_kses_post( $postdata['post_content'] );
            $post_excerpt   = wp_kses_post( $postdata['post_excerpt'] );
            $featured_image = absint( sanitize_text_field( $postdata['feat_image_id'] ) );
            <!-- i have added this line here to get regions id  -->
            $regionId       = sanitize_text_field($postdata['regions']);
            
            $product_id = wp_insert_post( $post_data );

                
                if ( $product_id ) {
                    
                    // and trying to assign this product id to region id like this.
                    wp_set_object_terms($product_id, $regionId, 'region');

}
```

But i see this is not working. Any idea how to fix this problem?

[FULL handle_product_add]

```
public function handle_product_add() {
        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( ! dokan_is_user_seller( get_current_user_id() ) ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( ! isset( $_POST['dokan_add_new_product_nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( sanitize_key( $_POST['dokan_add_new_product_nonce'] ), 'dokan_add_new_product' ) ) {
            return;
        }

        $postdata = wp_unslash( $_POST ); // phpcs:ignore

        $errors             = [];
        self::$product_cat  = - 1;
        self::$post_content = __( 'Details of your product ...', 'dokan-lite' );

        if ( isset( $postdata['add_product'] ) ) {
            $post_title     = sanitize_text_field( $postdata['post_title'] );
            $post_content   = wp_kses_post( $postdata['post_content'] );
            $post_excerpt   = wp_kses_post( $postdata['post_excerpt'] );
            $featured_image = absint( sanitize_text_field( $postdata['feat_image_id'] ) );
            $regionId       = sanitize_text_field($postdata['regions']);

            if ( empty( $post_title ) ) {
                $errors[] = __( 'Please enter product title', 'dokan-lite' );
            }

            if ( ! isset( $postdata['chosen_product_cat'] ) ) {
                if ( Helper::product_category_selection_is_single() ) {
                    if ( absint( $postdata['product_cat'] ) < 0 ) {
                        $errors[] = __( 'Please select a category', 'dokan-lite' );
                    }
                } else {
                    if ( ! isset( $postdata['product_cat'] ) || empty( $postdata['product_cat'] ) ) {
                        $errors[] = __( 'Please select at least one category', 'dokan-lite' );
                    }
                }
            } elseif ( empty( $postdata['chosen_product_cat'] ) ) {
                $errors[] = __( 'Please select a category', 'dokan-lite' );
            }

            self::$errors = apply_filters( 'dokan_can_add_product', $errors );

            if ( ! self::$errors ) {
                $timenow        = dokan_current_datetime()->setTimezone( new \DateTimeZone( 'UTC' ) );
                $product_status = dokan_get_new_post_status();
                $post_data      = apply_filters(
                    'dokan_insert_product_post_data', [
                        'post_type'         => 'product',
                        'post_status'       => $product_status,
                        'post_title'        => $post_title,
                        'post_content'      => $post_content,
                        'post_excerpt'      => $post_excerpt,
                        'post_date_gmt'     => $timenow->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ),
                        'post_modified_gmt' => $timenow->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ),
                    ]
                );

                $product_id = wp_insert_post( $post_data );

                
                if ( $product_id ) {
                    
                    wp_set_object_terms($product_id, $regionId, 'regions');
                    // set images
                    if ( $featured_image ) {
                        set_post_thumbnail( $product_id, $featured_image );
                    }

                    if ( isset( $postdata['product_tag'] ) && ! empty( $postdata['product_tag'] ) ) {
                        $tags_ids = array_map( 'absint', (array) $postdata['product_tag'] );
                        wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, $tags_ids, 'product_tag' );
                    }

                    /* set product category */
                    if ( ! isset( $postdata['chosen_product_cat'] ) ) {
                        if ( Helper::product_category_selection_is_single() ) {
                            wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, (int) $postdata['product_cat'], 'product_cat' );
                        } else {
                            if ( isset( $postdata['product_cat'] ) && ! empty( $postdata['product_cat'] ) ) {
                                $cat_ids = array_map( 'absint', (array) $postdata['product_cat'] );
                                wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, $cat_ids, 'product_cat' );
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        $chosen_cat = Helper::product_category_selection_is_single() ? [ reset( $postdata['chosen_product_cat'] ) ] : $postdata['chosen_product_cat'];
                        Helper::set_object_terms_from_chosen_categories( $product_id, $chosen_cat );
                    }

                    /** Set Product type, default is simple */
                    $product_type = empty( $postdata['product_type'] ) ? 'simple' : $postdata['product_type'];
                    wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, $product_type, 'product_type' );

                    // Gallery Images
                    if ( ! empty( $postdata['product_image_gallery'] ) ) {
                        $attachment_ids = array_filter( explode( ',', wc_clean( $postdata['product_image_gallery'] ) ) );
                        update_post_meta( $product_id, '_product_image_gallery', implode( ',', $attachment_ids ) );
                    }

                    if ( isset( $postdata['_regular_price'] ) ) {
                        update_post_meta( $product_id, '_regular_price', ( $postdata['_regular_price'] === '' ) ? '' : wc_format_decimal( $postdata['_regular_price'] ) );
                    }

                    if ( isset( $postdata['_sale_price'] ) ) {
                        update_post_meta( $product_id, '_sale_price', ( $postdata['_sale_price'] === '' ? '' : wc_format_decimal( $postdata['_sale_price'] ) ) );
                        $date_from = isset( $postdata['_sale_price_dates_from'] ) ? wc_clean( $postdata['_sale_price_dates_from'] ) : '';
                        $date_to   = isset( $postdata['_sale_price_dates_to'] ) ? wc_clean( $postdata['_sale_price_dates_to'] ) : '';
                        $now       = dokan_current_datetime();

                        // Dates
                        if ( $date_from ) {
                            update_post_meta( $product_id, '_sale_price_dates_from', $now->modify( $date_from )->setTime( 0, 0, 0 )->getTimestamp() );
                        } else {
                            update_post_meta( $product_id, '_sale_price_dates_from', '' );
                        }

                        if ( $date_to ) {
                            update_post_meta( $product_id, '_sale_price_dates_to', $now->modify( $date_to )->setTime( 23, 59, 59 )->getTimestamp() );
                        } else {
                            update_post_meta( $product_id, '_sale_price_dates_to', '' );
                        }

                        if ( $date_to && ! $date_from ) {
                            update_post_meta( $product_id, '_sale_price_dates_from', $now->setTime( 0, 0, 0 )->getTimestamp() );
                        }

                        if ( '' !== $postdata['_sale_price'] && '' === $date_to && '' === $date_from ) {
                            update_post_meta( $product_id, '_price', wc_format_decimal( $postdata['_sale_price'] ) );
                        } else {
                            update_post_meta( $product_id, '_price', ( $postdata['_regular_price'] === '' ) ? '' : wc_format_decimal( $postdata['_regular_price'] ) );
                        }
                        // Update price if on sale
                        if ( '' !== $postdata['_sale_price'] && $date_from && $now->modify( $date_from )->getTimestamp() < $now->getTimestamp() ) {
                            update_post_meta( $product_id, '_price', wc_format_decimal( $postdata['_sale_price'] ) );
                        }
                    }

                    update_post_meta( $product_id, '_visibility', 'visible' );
                    update_post_meta( $product_id, '_stock_status', 'instock' );

                    do_action( 'dokan_new_product_added', $product_id, $postdata );

                    if ( current_user_can( 'dokan_edit_product' ) ) {
                        $redirect = dokan_edit_product_url( $product_id );
                    } else {
                        $redirect = dokan_get_navigation_url( 'products' );
                    }

                    if ( 'create_and_add_new' === $postdata['add_product'] ) {
                        $redirect = add_query_arg(
                            [
                                'created_product'          => $product_id,
                                '_dokan_add_product_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'dokan_add_product_nonce' ),
                            ],
                            dokan_get_navigation_url( 'new-product' )
                        );
                    }

                    wp_safe_redirect( apply_filters( 'dokan_add_new_product_redirect', $redirect, $product_id ) );
                    exit;

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: And where/how does your `handle_product_add` method get called?

Comment: it called on a same file on a `__construct` function `add_action( 'template_redirect', [ $this, 'handle_product_add' ], 11 );`

Comment: What is `$postdata` supposed to be? It's not in the function scope, it is not a class property, and wasn't "imported" via `global` either.

Comment: And why via the `template_redirect` hook?

Comment: `And why via the template_redirect hook?` I does not know this couse just am editing plugin code and i am not very familiar with wordpress in fact. I also just added full function, just to be more clear maybe there is somethink i cant explain if you ask me, as i told i am beginer on wp development

Comment: We can't always tell what might be going wrong, just by looking at code. You will need to do a bit of actual debugging - you are the one sitting in front of the actual system, with the actual database content, etc.

Comment: Yes i know this. I am asking for a little assistence, maybe where should i look. I am trying to debug for about 3 days now. But am not finding any solution or where is the problem.

Comment: Start by verifying it goes into the if/else branches you expect it to go into. Check the return values of the WP functions you are calling, in most cases they will tell you about whether the operation succeeded or not. If you can't or don't want to set up a real debugger, so that you can step through the code in your IDE "live" as it executes, then make debug outputs instead.

Comment: (And if those would interrupt the process, because parts of it happen via AJAX were random debug outputs would invalidate JSON data or something, then you can also write your debug info to a file instead, and check the content of that afterwards.)

Comment: One fast questions , When i create new product as vendor i also chose categories . And categories is assigned successfully. Does this mean `/* set product category */` the code down this comment is working? So logically `if (..)` is working?